# Texto não fica centralizado dentro de um elemento div.row

Tags: html, css

Estou criando uma espécie de carteira online e estou organizando o Layout. Porém parece que o Bootstrap ou o CSS não está conseguindo interpretar meu comando. Ele não centraliza os textos SEMANA no meio da ROW.

```css
  body {

   margin: 0px;
}

#navbar {
position: absolute;
top: 165px;
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
background-color: #59b210;
}

#coluna {

margin-top: 30px;
}

#coluna1 {

height: auto;
background-color: yellow;


}

#coluna2 {

height: auto;
background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="coluna">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <h2><p class="text-center">NOME1</p><h2>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    <h2><p class="text-center">NOME2</p></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <h6><p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p></h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
   <h6><p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p></h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div id="coluna1" class="col"> 
  <div class="row">
   <p class="text-center">Semana 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p class="text-center">Semana 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p class="text-center">Semana 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p class="text-center">Semana 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p class="text-center">Semana 5</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="coluna2" class="col">
  <div class="row">
   <p class="text-center">Semana 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center">Semana 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center">Semana 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center">Semana 4</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center">Semana 5</p>
   </div>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tira essa class `row` das `divs` que têm os `p` dentro. Vc não deve deixar elementos soltos dentro de uma `row`, na verdade o filho direto de um `row` deve ser um `col`.

> In a `grid` layout, content must be placed within `columns` and only `columns` may be immediate children of `rows`.

Traduzindo: *"Em um layout de `grid`, o conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro de `columns` e apenas as `columns` podem ser filhos imediatos das `rows`."*

***Fonte oficial do próprio Bootstrap***: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Mas resumidamente basta remover a classe `row` da `div` pai do `p`, ou mesmo delete essa `div`, pois ela não faz sentido no código, já que um elemento `p` já ocupa `100%` da largura disponível.

```css
body {

    margin: 0px;
}

#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 165px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #59b210;
}

#coluna {

    margin-top: 30px;
}

#coluna1 {

    height: auto;
    background-color: yellow;


}

#coluna2 {

    height: auto;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div id="coluna">
        <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>
                        <p class="text-center">NOME1</p>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>
                        <p class="text-center">NOME2</p>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h6>
                    <p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p>
                </h6>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h6>
                    <p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p>
                </h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="coluna1" class="col">
                <p class="text-center">Sem Div por fora do P</p>

                <p class="text-center">Semana 2</p>

                <p class="text-center">Semana 3</p>

                <p class="text-center">Semana 4</p>

                <p class="text-center">Semana 5</p>
            </div>

            <div id="coluna2" class="col">
                <div class="">
                    <p class="text-center">Com Div por fora do P</p>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <p class="text-center">Semana 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <p class="text-center">Semana 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <p class="text-center">Semana 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <p class="text-center">Semana 5</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Por que "deve ser"? :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acordou cedo rapaz, haha! Bom fiz um **edit** na resposta explicando o "deve ser" ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado irmão e desculpe o erro juvenil kkkk abraços.

Comment: @BrunoMuniz tranquilo amigo, quando a gente usa a esses frameworks te umas regrinhas que a gente acaba sendo obrigado a seguir, abs

Answer (score 0):

Seus elementos `p` nao estao 100% dentro da `.row`. Experimente criar esta regra:

```css
.col .text-center {
  width: 100%;
}
```